# Using MapBox, need a good routing API that supports public transit (buses, trains)

Tags: c#, api, maps

I have been using Mapbox to make an app to help people get through cities, the only thing map box is missing is the Direction API does not support Public Transits. I have looked into using Googles GeoJSONs that support transit, but there is a breach in their terms of service doing this. Would anyone else have a recommendation for what I can use with MapBox? The testing phase of this app will be within Belfast.

Comment: Are you looking  for a free or paid solution?